# How search number within range formatted string using delimiter?

Tags: php

If my formatted string is:

```
$range = '0|500|0.50';
```

How can I search if number (200) exists in range between 0 and 500?

Here is what I tried, if there is better idea tell me please

Exploding the range first?

```
$arr = explode('|', $range);
$min = min($arr);
$max = max($arr);
```

But I do not know how to progress from there? I even do not know how to exlcude the 3rd parameter from range 0.50 in this case. Can anyone give me a starting point? I basically want to run search for numbers against range (formatted that way with | delimiter)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_pop()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) function to remove last element from array.

```
$arr = explode('|', $range);
$arr = array_pop($arr);
$min = min($arr);
$max = max($arr);
```

Then compare with min and max values...

Answer (score 0):

use this to get 1st and 2nd value of array

```
$arr = explode('|', $range);
$min = min($arr[0]);
$max = max($arr[1]);
```

and use if condition to check.